# Tmpfs директория /run занята на 100%, du -sh /run показавает что она пуста

Tags: debian, mount, tmpfs

В общем не знаю как решить проблемы с местом /var - занято на 100%.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]з
Не могу апустить docker контейнеры, пришлось удалить журналы journald. При

`du -sh /run`

показавает что она  практически пуста - занято только 50 мегабайт.

`lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'`

Не показал каких либо анамалий, которые можно причислить к директории /run.

Пока добалял свободное место

`mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /run -o remount,size=10G`

Но это не решение, сервер перезагружать - это Ка́рго-культ - не мой путь.

На серваке крутиться apache2(знаю скоро ему хана), postgres, mysql, docker.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в каталог `/run/lock` примонтирована другая файловая система. не перекрывает ли она те самые потерянные гигабайты? попробуйте примонтировать фс с опцией `--bind`: `$ mkdir /tmp/some; sudo mount --bind /run /tmp/some` и посмотрите на неё в «чистом виде»

Answer (score 1):

В общем я разобрался в чем была проблема. Она заключалась в

```
atopacct.service
```

Как я понял он не смог завершить задачу из-за того, что ранее я занулил его разросшийся лог файл я попытался сегодня его перезапустить через

```
systemctl restart atopacct.service
```

Он выдал ошибку

```
ноя 28 08:16:39 serv1 atopacctd[247166]: /run/pacct_shadow.d: File exists
ноя 28 08:16:39 serv1 systemd[1]: PID file /run/atopacctd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
ноя 28 08:16:39 serv1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Atop process accounting daemon.
ноя 28 08:16:39 serv1 systemd[1]: Unit atopacct.service entered failed state.
```

На bugs.debian.org я нашел решение в данной статье [bug=849138](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=849138)

```
- Downgrade to atop 1.26
- Reboot, or make sure atopacctd is stopped and remove /run/pacct_shadow.d 
directory.
- Upgrade to 2.26.
```

Я конечно просто сделал

```
rm -r /run/pacct_shadow.d
```

И

```
systemctl restart atopacct.service
```

Проблема решена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Три бэктика для выделения кода не работают в местном диалекте Markdown. Используйте отступ в 4 пробела, Ctrl+K.